# New Linux VM How to remote Connect from Windows?

Tags: linux, remote-access

My IT department installed a new Linux VM for me and gave me an account to SSH into the machine. I did that and changed the password via Putty.

I'm new to Linux and was wondering how do I remote connect to this machine and view the desktop from windows?

Answer (score 0):

Unless they gave you instructions, chances are you only have bash over SSH (putty) access to the VM. You should ask your it department.